# Matching text within a parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to check if 2 divs contain the same text, and if they do then add a style to the parent div. 
I have this working fine with the below code, but my problem is that the divs are all looking for a match and not just the divs that are in the parent? if you look at the below

```
<div class="infobox">
    <div class="date">8</div>
    <div class="secdate">8</div>
</div>
<div class="infobox">
    <div class="date">1</div>
    <div class="secdate">11</div>
</div>
<div class="infobox">
    <div class="date">8</div>
    <div class="secdate">11</div>
</div>
```

and the jQuery

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.date').each(function () {
        var myhtml = $(this).html().split(' ')[0];
        var ele = $(this);
        $('.secdate').each(function () {
            myhtml == $(this).html().split(' ')[0] ? $(ele).parent().css('background', '#ffff00') : ""
        })
    })
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/v7fa09bj/)

the third div is having the style applied, which it shouldn't as the 2 divs within don't match?

Comment: You have `$(this).html().split(' ')[0] == $(this).html().split(' ')[0]` ( myhtml == myhtml ).

Comment: here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bloodygeese/jyo4ynbo/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems much simpler:

```
$('.infobox').each(function () {
    if ($(this).find('.date').text() == $(this).find('.secdate').text()) $(this).css('background', '#ffff00')
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jyo4ynbo/1/)**

Loop over the parent (infobox) and just compare the text of the date child to the secdate child.

Comment: This is even better, though I'd still break it into variables for readability.

Comment: Thanks, thats great and explains quite a lot, but what if my mark up was like this http://jsfiddle.net/bloodygeese/Leaz5w3n/ and I wanted the style applied to the class 'secdate'

Comment: Well, that's a different question but I'll give it a go. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/44owwcg6/?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it should be simpler:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.date').each(function () {
        var dateText = $(this).text();
        var secdateText = $(this).next('.secdate').text();

        if (dateText == secdateText) {
            $(this).parent().css('background', '#ffff00');
        }
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/v7fa09bj/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I changed things a little bit:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.infobox').each(function () {           
        if( $(this).children('.date').html() == $(this).children('.secdate').html() )
            $(this).css('background', '#ffff00');
     });
 });
```

This way you don't even need a loop.
I tested here and it works like charm :)

Hope it helps